# If not working with indexpath

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am wondering why this is not working please help me.
Here is my code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 

*)indexPath
{
    if (selectedIndexPath == indexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = nil;
    } else {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath : indexPath animated : NO];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: what is selectedIndexPath type/declaration ?

Comment: it is previous clicked indexpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you retain your `selectedIndexPath` so it is not set to `nil` inadvertently.

```
@interface YourClass

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;

@end
```

Then refer to the variable as `self.selectedIndexPath` and you should be fine.

But there is a second caveat. `NSIndexPath` is an object, so the operator `==` will just compare the **pointer addresses**. Clearly, those will always be different because one is your variable and the other one is the method's private variable! What you want to use is either

```
if ([indexPath isEqualTo:selectedIndexPath]) // not tested
```

or

```
if (indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath.row && 
    indexPath.section == selectedIndexPath.section)
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSIndexPath` object consists of two parts they are row and section. The `indexPathForRow:inSection:` method creates an `NSIndexPath` object from row and section index numbers. Make sure your `selectedIndexPath` is created properly. Follow this [apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.